# Angular Passing a parameter to a child component changes the value of that parameter as a variable in the parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have not been able to understand this strange behavior for me:

I have a parent component named "parent-component". This has a form that once finished registering and saving a service is consumed to upload an image:

```
@ViewChild(FilesAliadoComponent, { static: false }) filesAliadoComponent: FilesAliadoComponent;

post(data) {
this.aliadoService.postAliado("aliado-region-pais/publico", data).subscribe(resultado => {
    let value1 = [{ key: "aliadoId", value: resultado.aliadoDTO.id }]
    let datosFoto = this.filesAliadoComponent.uploadPhoto(objectFile);
}, err => {
    let error = this.errorService.getErrors();
    this.modalGeneralService.modalShowError(error, Modals.ID_MESSAGE_MODAL)
    })
}
```

Focusing on the problem, the local variable "value1" assigned the object which can be seen in the code above. This variable is sent to the child component to the "uploadPhoto" method as a parameter and there it receives it without any problem:

```
uploadPhoto(value1Parameter) {
    let newValue = value1Parameter;
    if (typeof this.image.img != "undefined") {
      let datosFormulario = new FormData();
      newValue.push({ key: "archivo", value: this.image.img });
      datosFormulario = this.filesServices.dataFormFile(value1Parameter);
      return datosFormulario;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Now the problem is that when the child component receives the value of the parameter I assign it to "newValue" and when manipulating this variable both the value of "newValue" and the value of the variable "value1Parameter" are changed. For this case, what reaches the "value1Parameter" parameter I assign to the local variable "newValue", to the latter I insert a new position in the array. By doing this, I modify both values ​​and once I receive the response, the value of the local variable "value1" of the parent component also changes with the new position in the array.

Testing with breakpoints, from the console I change the value of "newValue" and "value1Parameter" and when I change one, the other always changes. I really don't understand why this happens.
And even stranger for me, is that the value that was sent as a parameter at the time of "Change", the parent component takes that new value for the global variable "value1"

thanks

Comment: Please change the references to 'Object File' and 'New Object' to reflect the actual names in your sample code, that would make it much easier to understand your question.  [This](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/) might help with an understanding of pass by reference.

Comment: Ready. Thanks for the comment, I hope it is more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript passes objects by reference so there is only one 'object' in memory.  So when you change a property on that object, the change is visible everywhere it is referenced.

```js
function changeName(person) { person.name = 'Jason'; }
var p = { name: 'Miguel' }
changeName(p); // will change p.name to be 'Jason'
```

To prevent that you can create a copy of the object:

```js
function changeName(person) {
  var obj = {...person}; // or var obj = Object.assign({}, person);
  obj.name = 'Jason';
}
var p = { name: 'Miguel' }
changeName(p); // p.name will still be 'Miguel' because we didn't change the passed object
```

Properties on the object area also references though, to this will add to the names list:

```js
function addName(people) {
  var obj = [...people];
  obj.names.push('Jason'); // obj.names and people.names refer to the same array
}
var p = { names: ['Miguel'] };
addName(p); // p.names will be ['Miguel', 'Jason']
```

To create a deep copy, I find it easy to convert the object to JSON and back to an object.
Converting back to an object from JSON will create new objects for all children and other descendants.

```js
function addName(people) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(people));
  obj.names.push('Jason'); // obj.names is now completely different than people.names
}
var p = { names: ['Miguel'] };
addName(p); // p.names will be ['Miguel']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have both `value1Parameter` and `newValue` pointing to the same array. You should think of those two variables as of 2 aliases for the same object (array in your case). So if you need to change one, but not change the other, you have to create a copy of your array like this:

```
let newValue = [...value1Parameter];
```

This creates a new array with all elements same as in the original one. Then you can new items to `newValue`, and it will not be reflected in the original one.